# mvc 5 ajax: httpError 400.0 Bad request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

having trouble with ajax i am using vs 2015 mvc 5.
following are the two model classes which have 1 to many relation.
i am facing some problem.

1. the view doesn't produce expected links i.e. instead
   **~/Global/Cities/Details/1** it result **~/Global/Cities/Details/** only.
2. when i fix that manually in browser it through **httperror 400.0 Bade Request**
3. when i remove **Url** property from ajax options the partial view opens in new tab window

```html
namespace WebApplication1.Areas.Global.Models
    {
        public class Organization
        {
            public virtual int OrganizationId { get; set; }
            public virtual int CityId { get; set; }
            public virtual string Name { get; set; }
            public virtual City city { get; set; }

        }


        public class City
        {
            public virtual int CityId { get; set; }
            public virtual string Name { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Organization> Organization { get;set; }

        }
    }
```

and this is the partial view controller..

```html
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            City city = db.Cities.Find(id);
            if (city == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return PartialView(city);
        }
```

```html
<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("Organizations",new SelectList(item.Organization, "OrganizationId","Name"))
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CityId }) |
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Details", "Details",item.CityId,
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                UpdateTargetId = "detail",
                Url = Url.Action("Details",item.CityId)
            }, new { id=item.CityId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CityId })
        </td>
</tr>
```

i have also render **jqueryval** bundle in layout page... 
is there any problem with my code please help....